# Does not swinging their arms helps a centaur gallop faster?

Tags: creature-design, anatomy, sports, centaur

I am comparing a centaur with a horse, so a centaur will not only weigh more since it has the torso of a human, but will also experience more drag due to a bigger surface area. I imagine that centaurs because of their higher center of gravity will need to keep their balance while galloping by swinging their arms to act as counterweights.
However, swinging the arms probably works for bipeds, so I wonder: does it also works for quadrupeds?
I need them to compete in events, so would you advise them to tuck their hands by the side when galloping?

Comment: Oh no, naruto-running centaurs :-(

Comment: @StarfishPrime Haha my first thought.

Comment: Humans correct the inbalance dynamically. It's a little like moving a barell by rocking it. The energy is stored and released (to the extent it is) in the legs and balance. Horses do the same just that they have a longer spine and four contact points to do it with. The arms can be used but most runners find that uses much more energy. As already commented, try Naruto running.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Sideways unbalance for biped, not for quadruped**

When a biped is running, his one leg is touching the ground, while the other leg is in the air. This can create a sideways unbalance. To overcome this unbalance, he swings his arms in coordination with legs. But when a quadruped is galloping, his two legs are touching the ground (front or rear) and other two are in the air. He does not feel a sideways unbalance. But he use his arms for other purposes like throwing a javelin, using bow and arrow, using sword and shield or carrying something.

Comment: I am pretty sure that horses can run in a way that all four of their legs are off the ground for part of the cycle. Used to be the style to do paintings of horses with at least one foot on the ground all the time even in full gallop. Also, for some paces they will have non-symmetric foot-to-ground contact. They correct this dynamically, much as humans.

Comment: Hmmm... initially, I thought it had to do with assisting with breathing. During my research, i found this article that would support your claim. https://www.science.org/content/article/why-you-should-swing-your-arms-when-you-run You should add it to your post to support your answer.

Comment: For the purpose of balance he should throw TWO javelins.